# Handling long lived state in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building an application that requires a user to be a certain age before entering the site. The user is shown a form in which they must enter their date of birth, this information is then saved to local storage and then on every request check if that value is set in local storage. Currently inside `main.js` the checking code looks like:

```
let hasRememberedAge = localStorage.getItem('ageVerified')
if (hasRememberedAge !== null) {
  store.dispatch(ageVerified())
}
```

This feels wrong, my question what is a better way to handle this? Should I fire an action on every page load which then triggers these checks? If so where should this `dispatch` live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this. You can do this wherever you create the store.

Alternatively you can serialize a part of your state in a `store.subscribe` callback, and read it from the `localStorage` before creating the store. You can pass such persisted state as a second argument to `createStore` to preload it.